# How can I modify my functions to use list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Specifically when removing the stop letters from this getwords function.

```
def getwords(fileName):
  file = open(fileName, 'r')
  text = file.read()
  stopletters = [".", ",", ";", ":", "'s", '"', "!", "?", "(", ")", '“', '”']
  text = text.lower()
  for letter in stopletters:
   text = text.replace(letter, "")
  words = text.split()
  return words
```

And for the loop in this bigrams function

```
def compute_bigrams(fileName):
  input_list = getwords(fileName)
  bigram_list = {}
  for i in range(len(input_list) - 1):
    if input_list[i] in bigram_list:
      bigram_list[input_list[i]] = bigram_list[input_list[i]] + [input_list[i + 1]]
    else :
     bigram_list[input_list[i]] = [input_list[i + 1]]
  return bigram_list
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, any reason to use list comprehension? for loops work just as well and can be more readable (in my opinion) for complicated cases.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I suggest replacing that `for i in range():` with a `for elem in iterable:`. Use a context manager to handle files.

Comment: ... by writing a list comprehension that performs the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it in this way:

```
def getwords(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read().lower()

    stop_letters = (".", ",", ";", ":", "'s", '"', "!", "?", "(", ")", '“', '”')
    text = ''.join([letter if letter not in stop_letters else '' for letter in text])

    words = text.split()
    return words
```

I used context manager for file open, merged some lines (no need to have a special line for `.lower()`) and used list comprehension to go trough text and add letters but only if that letter is not in `stop_letters`. After joining that list you get the same results.

Note that you can use generator expression as well which would be even better:

`text = ''.join((letter if letter not in stop_letters else '' for letter in text))`

And if you really want to save that one line you could just do:

`return text.split()`

Comment: Maybe use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension - it won't create an unnecessary list - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Comment: Yes I agree it would be better but OP asked specifically for list comprehension. I'll edit the answer for that note.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the first replacement without a for loop at all by incorporating a little bit of regex:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile('''[.,;:"!?()“”]*|'s*''')
pattern.sub('', 'this is a test string (it proves that the replacements work!).')


>>> 'this is a test string it proves that the replacements work'
```

Though it theoretically is possible to make your second loop into a comprehension, I strongly recommend you don't do it. People, including yourself in a few months' time will have severe problems understanding what it does. As @Alexander Cécile noted in the comments, you can refactor the second loop utilizing `for input in input_list`, adding to the performance and readability of your code